# What "small military installation" did the US have in Cambodia as recently as 2019 (per Gannett graphic), and what was/is its function?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, military, cambodia

In an animated graphic embedded in CNN"s December 9, 2023 [Study says US military intervention in the world is backfiring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvppoDl66Ak) a dark gray dot indicating "small military installation" appears starting in 1971 (according to the animation) and is still there in 2019 and perhaps 2020<sup>1</sup>.

It's a world map and the dots are huge, but it looks like the location is in the general area of Phnom Penh, perhaps in the direction of Vietnam's Ho Chi Minh City.

The animation is credited to [Gannett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gannett) and may be from [USA Today](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USA_Today).

In Wikipedia's [List of United States military bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_military_bases) which lists many international sites, is no mention of Cambodia.

Then again, the dot indicates "small military installation" and not "military base".

**Question:** What "small military installation" did the US have in Cambodia as recently as 2019<sup>1</sup> per this Gannett animated graphic, and what was/is its function?

---

<sup>1</sup>the animation rolls over from 2020 to 1945 by dissolving so I can't be certain of the status in 2020 per the graphic.

[image: screenshot of animated graphic by Gannett in CNN's "Study says US military intervention in the world is backfiring" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KvppoDl66Ak showing a small military installation in (I think) Cambodia as recent as 2019]

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly this was US personnel at Ream Naval Base.

From: https://www.voacambodia.com/a/cambodia-funds-cadets-at-u-s-universities-after-scholarships-end-over-strained-relations/5955283.html

> In 2020, the U.S. military was told it was no longer welcome at Ream Naval Base, near Sihanoukville Port, and two U.S.-funded facilities there were torn down.

News outlets frequently over emphasize "US military" installations. 2 people at an office at an airport, just for liaison duties, count as "military installation".

What was the function? Seems to be a RHIB maintenance shed.

> Before and after: Satellite imagery shows the Rigid-Hulled Inflatable Boat Maintenance Facility at Ream naval base was still standing on October 1, 2020 but had been completely dismantled by November 4

Comment: And for the "...and what was/is its function?" aspect, is it possible to add at least something about the "two U.S.-funded facilities"? *Thanks!*